# Как реализовать хлебные крошки на codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как реализовать хлебные крошки на codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Autocrumb: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/137949/

Comment: @satanlucas, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦, по ссылке дан более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Информацию по ссылке могут удалить, в этом случае ваше экспертное мнение может помочь разобраться в проблеме в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивалася с такой же проблемой, и решил написать свою библиотеку которая решает вопрос с подгрузкой шаблонов и возможностью создавать хлебные крошки (автоматически или самому).

Ссылка на библиотеку:

https://github.com/danieltorscho/CI_Template_lib

Документация прилогается. Но вот именно то что вам нужно:

```
$this->template->crumb('E-commerce', 'ecommerce/index'); // 1-я хл.кр. со ссылкой
$this->template->crumb('Products', 'ecommerce/products'); // 2-я хл.кр. со сылкой 
$this->template->crumb('Product #391'); 3-я хл.кр. без ссылки
```